# Insertar una tabla deserdonada en otra en t-sql

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

tengo una tabla (tabla1) que quiero desordenarla y insertar la en otra tabla (tabla6), lo hecho de esta forma: con el select into:

```
select * into tabla6 from (select * from tabla1 order by newid());
```

pero me da este error

> La cláusula ORDER BY no es válida en vistas, funciones insertadas,
> tablas derivadas, subconsultas ni expresiones de tabla común, salvo
> que se especifique también TOP, OFFSET o FOR XML.

Comment: ¿y hacer directamente `select * into tabla6 from tabla1 order by newid()`, no funciona?

Comment: funciona pero me da una tabla ordenada, tabla6 ordenada, lo querria desordenada con el uso de newid() o otra instruccion similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única forma que encontré para  que meta los registros desordenados, es esta opción.

Dado que no deja incluir el order en la subconsulta, entonces obtengo la cantidad de los ítems que están en mi `tabla1` y meto ese valor en el top de mi subconsulta.

```
declare @top as integer = (select count(1) from tabla1 )

drop table if exists tabla6 
select * 
into tabla6
from (
    select TOP (@top) * from tabla1  order by newid()
) x

SELECT * FROM tabla6
```

Comment: eso funciona perfectamiente muchas gracias, tengo una pregunta que es esto de "x" ?

Comment: x es solo un alias que le asignas a tu subconsulta